# JAVA - error variable for do.. while

Tags: java

I having issue when compiling my assignment code.

When I use the scanner input for the switch menu as integer value, the `do-while` is working fine, but due to assignment requirement, the menu input need to be char, so I alter it as below, but it keeps giving me error stating the variable of `m` is not found.

```
do {
  System.out.println(displayMenu(""));
  option = scn.nextLine();
  char m = option.charAt(0);

  switch (m) {    
    case 'A': TMA_Q3.enterInput(0); break;
    case 'B': System.out.println(" "); break;
    case 'C': System.out.println(""); break;  
    case 'D': System.out.println(""); break;
    case 'E': System.out.println(""); break;
    case 'F': System.out.println(""); break;

  }
} while(m != 'F'); // error occurs on this line stating m is not found
```

Comment: you will have to predefine M outside/ before the do, or it runs out of scope

Comment: *searching for the error message* would yield useful results .. also, make sure to include the copy'n'paste.

Answer (score 8):

`m` is out of scope `do {` because you define it inside `do {`.

Try to refactor like this:

```
char m;
do {
    System.out.println(displayMenu(""));
    option= scn.nextLine();
    m = option.charAt(0);
    ...
```

Comment: and assign it with some default value

Comment: +1 @JigarJoshi, as it may throw `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` if input is **blank**.

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare `m` out of `do`:

```
char m='';

do {
    //...
} while(m!='F');
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable `m` is out of scope. You will need to define it outside the `do ... while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(displayMenu(""));
option= scn.nextLine();
char m='';
```

> must be outside the do statement.
>   Try to Reverse your code int this code below:

```
System.out.println(displayMenu(""));
option= scn.nextLine();
char m =option.charAt(0);
do{
   m =option.charAt(0);
switch (m) {    case 'A': TMA_Q3.enterInput(0);break;
                 case 'B': System.out.println(" "); break;
                 case 'C': System.out.println(""); break;  
                 case 'D': System.out.println(""); break;
                 case 'E': System.out.println(""); break;
                 case 'F': System.out.println(""); break;

               }
} 
 while( m!='F');
```